# AS3: Tile based movement system

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tile

very new to as3 and using a tutorial found [here](http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/creating-simple-tile-system-in-as3-part.html) to try my hand at tile based movement. However, i cant seem to get the code to work. I keep getting the error code:

```
"1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:hero."
```

The line it is reference is:

```
var character: hero = new hero();
```

My full code is:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class main2 extends MovieClip {
        var hero;
        public function main2() {
            // Create map

            var mapWidth = 10;
            var mapHeight = 10;
            var tileSide = 32;
            var totalTiles = mapWidth * mapHeight;
            var myMap: Array = [
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
            ];

            for (var i: int = 0; i < mapHeight; i++) {
                for (var u: int = 0; u < mapWidth; u++) {
                    var cell: MovieClip = new tile();
                    cell.gotoAndStop(myMap[i][u] + 1);
                    cell.x = tileSide * u;
                    cell.y = tileSide * i;
                    addChild(cell);
                }
            }

            // Hero management

            var heroSpawnX = 4;
            var heroSpawnY = 2;

            var character: hero = new hero();
            addChild(character);
            character.x = heroSpawnX * tileSide;
            character.y = heroSpawnY * tileSide;

            var heroX = heroSpawnX;
            var heroY = heroSpawnY;

            // Basic movement

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, movement);

            function movement(event: KeyboardEvent):void {
                if (event.keyCode == 40 && myMap[heroY + 1][heroX] == 0) {
                    character.gfx.rotation = 0;
                    character.y +=  tileSide;
                    heroY++;
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 38 && myMap[heroY - 1][heroX] == 0) {
                    character.gfx.rotation = 180;
                    character.y -=  tileSide;
                    heroY--;
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 39 && myMap[heroY][heroX + 1] == 0) {
                    character.gfx.rotation = 270;
                    character.x +=  tileSide;
                    heroX++;
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 37 && myMap[heroY][heroX - 1] == 0) {
                    character.gfx.rotation = 90;
                    character.x -=  tileSide;
                    heroX--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Any help on this issue would be great, been at it for an hour now.

also if you have any recommendations on as3 resources please let me know...specifically tiled based systems.

thanks is advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means your class `Hero` is not found. you should put the `hero.as` file at where your `main2.as` file is(at same location as `main2.as`). and then import it:

```
import Hero;
```

and my recommendation on as3 resources:
1.http://republicofcode.com:I think best site for starting as3.I started from it.

2.http://kirupa.com: a good site with a lot of articles

3.http://flashandmath.com: for professionals

and don't forget Adobe ActionScript-3 API reference:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/

I   H☺ P E   this helps !